# Overriding getContextMenuInfo() from custom Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-adapter, custom-lists, android-contextmenu

I am building a list that had to be able to reorder the item's position.

Fortunately for me, I've found an [external library which has exactly what I needed](https://github.com/woxblom/DragListView).

Unfortunately, I could not implement a delete item action using onContextItemSelected() because menuInfo keeps always returning null, so I cannot read the position of selected item I wish to delete.

[This user blog post](https://vinaybhargav.wordpress.com/2014/07/20/android-floating-context-menu-for-listviewgridview/) gave a solution by overriding getContextMenuInfo().

> If item.getMenuInfo() is null in onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) method, I guess you are using custom ListView or GridView instead of android default ones. In such case, your custom View is not implementing getContextMenuInfo() method. Don’t worry we can fix that if you have its source. Open the view file and override the method getContextMenuInfo().

I have tried this in many ways, but it seems I am doing things wrong.

Is this the only solution or am I missing something?

## Activity

```
public class SurveyAdd extends AppCompatActivity {

private ArrayList<Pair<Long, String>> mItemArray = new ArrayList<>();
private DragListView mDragListView;
ItemAdapter listAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_survey_add);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    mDragListView = (DragListView) findViewById(R.id.surveyadd_list);
    mDragListView.getRecyclerView().setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    mDragListView.setDragListListener(new DragListView.DragListListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemDragStarted(int position) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemDragEnded(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
            if (fromPosition != toPosition) {
                setSurveyChange(true);
            }
        }
    });

    mDragListView.setCanDragHorizontally(false);
    mDragListView.setCustomDragItem(new MyDragItem(context, R.layout.item_survey_add));
    mDragListView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));


        mDragListView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        ItemAdapter listAdapter = new ItemAdapter(mItemArray, R.layout.item_survey_add, R.id.item_add_image_button, false);
        mDragListView.setAdapter(listAdapter, true);

    registerForContextMenu(mDragListView);
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_survey_add_item, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.surveyadd_action_delete:
            if (item.getMenuInfo() == null) {
                Toast.makeText(SurveyAdd.this, "NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    int position = info.position;  // CAN'T USE THIS, ALWAYS THROWS NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION
    Toast.makeText(SurveyAdd.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
    }
}
}
// The activity was simplified for posting
```

## ItemAdapter

imported and edited class

```
public class ItemAdapter extends DragItemAdapter<Pair<Long, String>, ItemAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private int mLayoutId;
private int mGrabHandleId;

public ItemAdapter(ArrayList<Pair<Long, String>> list, int layoutId, int grabHandleId, boolean dragOnLongPress) {
    super(dragOnLongPress);
    mLayoutId = layoutId;
    mGrabHandleId = grabHandleId;
    setHasStableIds(true);
    setItemList(list);
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(mLayoutId, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position);
    String text = mItemList.get(position).second;
    String[] separated = text.split("::");
    holder.mText.setText(separated[1]);
    holder.itemView.setTag(text);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return mItemList.get(position).first;
}

public class ViewHolder extends DragItemAdapter<Pair<Long, String>, ItemAdapter.ViewHolder>.ViewHolder {
    public TextView mText;
    public ImageView mIcon;

    public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView, mGrabHandleId);
        mText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_add_question);
        mIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(mGrabHandleId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClicked(View view) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClicked(View view) {

        return false;
    }
}
}
```

## DragListView

imported and locked class

```
public class DragListView extends FrameLayout {

public interface DragListListener {
    void onItemDragStarted(int position);

    void onItemDragEnded(int fromPosition, int toPosition);
}

private DragItemRecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private DragListListener mDragListListener;
private DragItem mDragItem;
private boolean mDragEnabled = true;
private float mTouchX;
private float mTouchY;

public DragListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public DragListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public DragListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();
    mDragItem = new DragItem(getContext());
    mRecyclerView = createRecyclerView();
    mRecyclerView.setDragItem(mDragItem);
    addView(mRecyclerView);
    addView(mDragItem.getDragItemView());
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    boolean retValue = handleTouchEvent(event);
    return retValue || super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    boolean retValue = handleTouchEvent(event);
    return retValue || super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

private boolean handleTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    mTouchX = event.getX();
    mTouchY = event.getY();
    if (isDragging()) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                mRecyclerView.onDragging(event.getX(), event.getY());
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                mRecyclerView.onDragEnded();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private DragItemRecyclerView createRecyclerView() {
    final DragItemRecyclerView recyclerView = (DragItemRecyclerView) LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.drag_item_recycler_view, this, false);
    recyclerView.setMotionEventSplittingEnabled(false);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    recyclerView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    recyclerView.setDragItemListener(new DragItemRecyclerView.DragItemListener() {
        private int mDragStartPosition;

        @Override
        public void onDragStarted(int itemPosition, float x, float y) {
            getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            mDragStartPosition = itemPosition;
            if (mDragListListener != null) {
                mDragListListener.onItemDragStarted(itemPosition);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDragging(int itemPosition, float x, float y) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onDragEnded(int newItemPosition) {
            if (mDragListListener != null) {
                mDragListListener.onItemDragEnded(mDragStartPosition, newItemPosition);
            }
        }
    });
    return recyclerView;
}

public RecyclerView getRecyclerView() {
    return mRecyclerView;
}

public DragItemAdapter getAdapter() {
    if (mRecyclerView != null) {
        return (DragItemAdapter) mRecyclerView.getAdapter();
    }
    return null;
}

public void setAdapter(DragItemAdapter adapter, boolean hasFixedItemSize) {
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(hasFixedItemSize);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.setDragEnabled(mDragEnabled);
    adapter.setDragStartedListener(new DragItemAdapter.DragStartedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDragStarted(View itemView, long itemId) {
            mRecyclerView.onDragStarted(itemView, itemId, mTouchX, mTouchY);
        }
    });
}

public void setLayoutManager(RecyclerView.LayoutManager layout) {
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layout);
}

public void setDragListListener(DragListListener listener) {
    mDragListListener = listener;
}

public boolean isDragEnabled() {
    return mDragEnabled;
}

public void setDragEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    mDragEnabled = enabled;
    if (mRecyclerView.getAdapter() != null) {
        ((DragItemAdapter) mRecyclerView.getAdapter()).setDragEnabled(mDragEnabled);
    }
}

public void setCustomDragItem(DragItem dragItem) {
    removeViewAt(1);

    DragItem newDragItem;
    if (dragItem != null) {
        newDragItem = dragItem;
    } else {
        newDragItem = new DragItem(getContext());
    }

    newDragItem.setCanDragHorizontally(mDragItem.canDragHorizontally());
    newDragItem.setSnapToTouch(mDragItem.isSnapToTouch());
    mDragItem = newDragItem;
    mRecyclerView.setDragItem(mDragItem);
    addView(mDragItem.getDragItemView());
}

public boolean isDragging() {
    return mRecyclerView.isDragging();
}

public void setCanDragHorizontally(boolean canDragHorizontally) {
    mDragItem.setCanDragHorizontally(canDragHorizontally);
}

public void setSnapDragItemToTouch(boolean snapToTouch) {
    mDragItem.setSnapToTouch(snapToTouch);
}

public void setCanNotDragAboveTopItem(boolean canNotDragAboveTop) {
    mRecyclerView.setCanNotDragAboveTopItem(canNotDragAboveTop);
}

public void setScrollingEnabled(boolean scrollingEnabled) {
    mRecyclerView.setScrollingEnabled(scrollingEnabled);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but i figured it out using that same draglistview.

Im using Xamarin but it's close enough to the same. Just type the C# in Java as necessary:

```
protected override IContextMenuContextMenuInfo ContextMenuInfo
    {
        get
        {
            IContextMenuContextMenuInfo menuInfo = base.ContextMenuInfo;
            if (menuInfo == null)
            {
                IListAdapter adapter = Adapter;
                int pos = GetPositionForView(selectedView);
                menuInfo = new AdapterContextMenuInfo(selectedView, pos, adapter.GetItemId(pos));
            }
            return menuInfo;
        }
    }


public void OnLongPress(MotionEvent e){
        int position = PointToPosition(mDownX, mDownY);
        int itemNum = position - FirstVisiblePosition;
        selectedView = GetChildAt(itemNum); //class variable
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Nate!